# TWEENJS strange yoyo threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, tweenjs

After one success circle of animation, tweenjs gets me twitching, i wanna create infinity moving animation, from top, to bottom, but i have some bugs in my code
I need help!
http://weblife.su/WineBazar/1/

```js
  var group_position_1 = new TWEEN.Tween(group.position)
                .to({ y: THREE.Math.degToRad(-20)}, 1000)
                .yoyo(true)
                .repeat(1)
                .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None)
                .onStart(() => {
                })
                .onUpdate(() => {
                })
                .onComplete(() => {
                               group_position_2.start()
                })
              var group_position_2 = new TWEEN.Tween(group.position)
                   .to({ y: THREE.Math.degToRad(-30)}, 1000)
                   .yoyo(true)
                   .repeat(1)
                   .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None) 
                   .onStart(() => {
                   })
                   .onUpdate(() => {
                   })
                   .onComplete(() => {
                             group_position_1.start()
                   })
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity: why do you set position in radians? And why do you set `yoyo` in general, if you already looped your tweens in `.onComplete()`?

Answer (score 0):

With GSAP v3, you can yoyo indefinitely by setting `.repeat(-1)`, [as explained in their docs](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Tween/repeat()):

> To repeat indefinitely, use -1.

```js
var group_position_1 = new TWEEN.Tween(group.position)
    .to({ y: -0.5}, 1000)
    .yoyo(true)
    .repeat(-1)
```

An aside: Degrees or radians are typically reserved for rotations. I don't think you need radians when setting the y-position when you can just use a hard value like 0.5.